# What are the pet health considerations for selamectin for treating parasites?

Tags: health, fleas

[Selamectin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selamectin) is a topical flea and other parasite treatment for pets.

Is there any evidence supporting health concerns in humans or pets with the use of selamectin for treating fleas? What dosage/application rate is documented as safe or unsafe?

Answer (score 1):

Selemectin is an Avermectin-like drug and is registered in some countries (in the form of for example Revolution top spot) for the use in dogs and cats to treat and manage fleas. Some trials are also going on to test efficiency against Sarcoptic and Demodectic mange. It is only registered for dogs and cats and in fact the pamphlet recommends washing your hands if you as a human came in contact with it. It is considered very safe at recommended dosages, i.e. Revolution are sold according to the size of the pet.